# How to manipulate inequalities and equalites in Coq?

Tags: coq

I struggle to find tactics or rewrite rules for Coq to apply well-known propertires of both equalities and inequalities such as: transform `H: a < b` into `H: a + c < b + c` or transform `a = b` into `a + c = b + c`.

Any time I have to prove obvious things related to arithmetics, it generally comes to the chaotic bunch of `cut`'s and verbose explanations of very basic facts, which is far from readability which I want to achieve.

Are there any ways to make this a bit less verbose?

Comment: Have you considered using the `lia` tactic (`Require Import Lia.` first) to deal with a lot of arithmetic goals?

Comment: Looks like a thing I was looking for. Looks like it could remove the most of headache.